# Laravel sends scheduled emails with incorrectly counted rows of mesasges which have been received last 24 hours

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, php-carbon

I created Laravel App in which I use command which sends emails to each its user with count of messages user received in his chat, notifications from the app and folowers who had followed him for the last 24 hours(1 day)

I'm trying to count messages, notifications and followers user has received for the last 24 hours.

When I test that - it works fine. (When I test that I set up datetime for scheduler on 2-3 minutes ahead and wait for the result or just run command which gives me the results directly via console)

The problem appears when I'm trying to get all the results for the last 24 hours. I noticed - it doesn't work at all, it always shows me '0' in the counters.

I assume the problem somewhere in date formatting but can't see any bugs in it.

When I test it works, but when I wait 24 hours - it doesn't work, and I must fix that faster, not wait days to catch the bug

Here's the code for scheduler:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
     $schedule->command('command:send_user_general_info_to_email')
              ->daily()->at('13:00')->timezone('Europe/London');
}
```

Here's the code for counting messages, notifications and followers for the last 24 hours:

```
public function handle() {

    $new_messages_amount = 0;
    $new_followers_amount = 0;
    $new_notifications_amount = 0;

    // chunk all the user in the app when send emails
    User::chunk(300, function( $users ) {

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            $new_messages_amount = Chat::where('user_id', $user->id )
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24)->toDateTimeString() )
                ->where('type', 1)
                ->count();

            $new_followers_amount = DB::table('followers')
                ->where('following_id', $user->id)
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24)->toDateTimeString() )
                ->count();

            $new_notifications_amount = $user->unreadNotifications()
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>',  Carbon::now()->subHours(24)->toDateTimeString() )
                ->count();

            if ( $user->email ) { // if user has email not NULL

                $user_info = [
                    'username' => $user->first_name,
                    'new_messages_amount' => $new_messages_amount,
                    'new_followers_amount' => $new_followers_amount,
                    'new_notifications_amount' => $new_notifications_amount,
                ];

                Mail::to( $user->email )->queue( new DailyOverviewMail($user_info) );
            }
        }

        // make a delay for 1 minute
        sleep(60);
    });

}
```

Comment: It looks like it should be okay, but you may want to turn on mysql logging and watch the query log to see what exactly is being passed in.

Comment: You have tested it on the sever or on your system? In your scheduler log the query and run the same query on your server mysql and check the result

Comment: Not sure if you need to use `whereDate` if you're comparing the whole datetime string. I haven't played around with those functions but it seems like they're for comparing specific parts of the date, not the whole thing. Trying just using `where`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `whereDate` which compares the dates only and not the complete timestamp. In combination with `>` (instead of `>=`), this will only return entries of the current day (at best). Simply replace it with `where` and you are good.

---

Your code can be improved significantly by replacing the extra queries with subqueries. This way, there will only be one query per chunk and not `1 + 3*300 = 901`.

```
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::query()
        ->select('*')
        ->selectSub(
            Chat::query()
                ->whereColumn('users.id', 'chats.user_id')
                ->where('created_at', '>', now()->subHours(24))
                ->where('type', 1)
                ->count(),
            'new_messages'
        )
        ->selectSub(
            DB::table('followers')
                ->whereColumn('users.id', 'followers.following_id')
                ->where('created_at', '>', now()->subHours(24))
                ->count(),
            'new_followers'
        )
        ->selectSub(
            DatabaseNotification::query()
                ->whereColumn('users.id', 'notifications.user_id')
                ->whereNull('read_at')
                ->where('created_at', '>', now()->subHours(24))
                ->count(),
            'new_unread_notifications'
        )
        ->chunkById(300, function ($users) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                if ($user->email) {
                    $user_info = [
                        'username' => $user->first_name,
                        'new_messages_amount' => $user->new_messages,
                        'new_followers_amount' => $user->new_followers,
                        'new_notifications_amount' => $user->new_unread_notifications,
                    ];

                    Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new DailyOverviewMail($user_info));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

*Note: the `select('*')` (or alternatively `select()`) is required to avoid `selectSub()` overriding the select list.*

As you are queuing the mails, there is also no need to `sleep(60)` in my opinion...

Comment: Man, thank you! It's so helpful! 
I will try that now and look if it works, will let you know here :) 
Thanks again!

Comment: Oh yeah, you should probably use `chunkById()` because there is no `orderBy` in the query. But I guess you figured that out already because normally it throws an error rather quickly.